# This is the question of merging two sorted lists. I could understand where is the problem?

Tags: merge, linked-list, mergesort

The program accepts two sorted linked lists and returns one linked list by merging these linked lists. I have written the logic considering edge cases too but the output is not coming. I think the problem lies in the formation of a third linked list. I am unable to form the third linked list.

```
class Solution {
public:
    ListNode *mergeTwoLists(ListNode *l1, ListNode *l2) {
        ListNode *l3 = new ListNode(0);
        ListNode *head = l3;
        ListNode *temp = new ListNode();
        if (!l1 && !l2) {
            return l1;
        } else if (!l1) {
            return l2;
        } else if (!l2) {
            return l1;
        } else if (l1->val <= l2->val) {
            l3->val = l1->val;
            l1 = l1->next;
        } else {
            l3->val = l2->val;
            l2 = l2->next;
        }
        while (l1->next || l2->next) {
            print(head);
            print(l1);
            print(l2);
            if (l1->val <= l2->val) {
                temp->val = l1->val;
                l1 = l1->next;
            } else {
                temp->val = l2->val;
                l2 = l2->next;
           }
            print(temp);
            //l3 = l3->next;
            l3->next = temp;
            l3 = l3->next;
        }
        return head;
    }
};
```

Comment: I would specify what you mean by "no output is coming". What is the output?  Nothing at all, null, incorrect..

Comment: It is time exceed problem

Comment: @mansithakur:  you can accept one of the answers y clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 2):

Your core problem lies in the fact that you're not allocating new nodes for every item in the new list:

You start with l3 being a new ListNode representing the start of the merged list, and set `l3->val` to the proper starting value (min of `l1->val` and `l2->val`). Later on, you're doing something similar with `temp`, evaluating the "current" nodes of the lists, which are now pointed to by l1 and l2, and setting `temp->val` to the minimum of the two. **The problem lies** in that l1, l2, l3, and temp are all **pointers** to ListNodes. You're repeatedly setting l3->next to point to the same piece of memory (pointed to by temp) with the underlying value member being overwritten on every loop iteration. My advice would be to think of temp's job as "handing off" the ListNode it points to (becomes `l3->next`) and changing to point to a new piece of memory to hold a new ListNode (for the next iteration), or better yet get rid of temp altogether by extracting the min **value** out of l1 or l2 and doing a simple `l3->next = new ListNode(min_val)`. It might help to draw out a memory diagram with l1, l2, and l3 quite literally pointing to separate pieces of memory, that way you can move arrows around and catch some more edge cases.

A few other things that could trip you up:

1) Think about your loop condition -- you've set (both before and in the loop) `l1 = l1->next` or `l2 = l2->next` and proceeded to refer to that **new** value's `next` member in the loop condition without checking whether or not that new value was null itself. This pitfall (a null dereference) can also affect checking the val member when you've gotten to the end of one list, but not the other.

2) Your starting `l3->val` is 0, and using arbitrary numbers isn't generally great practice. This would be a great time to consolidate, something like `ListNode* l3 = new ListNode(min(l1->val, l2->val))` after having checked that l1 and l2 both aren't null.

3) Your very first conditional isn't useful because (if I'm assuming correctly to return null if both lists are empty) one list being null simply means returning the other list is correct, which happens via the following two conditionals anyways.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to merge the lists, you should not be allocating new nodes but just change the `next` members to form a single ordered list. There are 2 phases:

- as long as you have nodes in both lists, compare the head node to determine from which list to take the first element and link that to the merged list.
- when one of the lists is exhausted, link the other list at the end of the merged list.

To link an element at the end of the merged list, you keep a pointer to the last node.

Here is a modified version:

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    ListNode *mergeTwoLists(ListNode *l1, ListNode *l2) {
        ListNode *head = NULL;
        ListNode *tail = NULL;
        ListNode *n;
        while (l1 && l2) {
            if (l1->val <= l2->val) {
                n = l1;
                l1 = l1->next;
            } else {
                n = l2;
                l2 = l2->next;
            }
            if (tail) {
                tail = tail->next = n;
            } else {
                tail = head = n;
            }
        }
        if (l1) {
            n = l1;
        } else {
            n = l2;
        }
        if (tail) {
            tail->next = n;
        } else {
            head = n;
        }
        return head;
    }
};
```

Once you master double pointers, you can improve this code and remove the tests for the head node:

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    ListNode *mergeTwoLists(ListNode *l1, ListNode *l2) {
        ListNode *head = NULL;
        ListNode **nextp = &head;
        while (l1 && l2) {
            if (l1->val <= l2->val) {
                *nextp = l1;
                nextp = &l1->next;
                l1 = l1->next;
            } else {
                *nextp = l2;
                nextp = &l2->next;
                l2 = l2->next;
            }
        }
        *nextp = l1 ? l1 : l2;
        return head;
    }
};
```